# form_for in pages other than create and edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

I'm new to development on rails and I needed a bit of help

I was working on a project for cataloging projects in our college.

I have a controller and an associated model called projects. I would like to have a form_for in the Show page of projects.

Is that even possible?

If so, Any idea on how I can go about this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can. First initialize your Model object in show method like this:

```
def show
 @project = Project.new
end
```

and in your show.html.erb, use for_for like this:

```
<%= form_for @project do %>

   ##your form stuff

<% end %>
```

Hope it will help. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A good practice is usually to put your form inside a file of its own (partial), so if you need it in other places, you can easily use it

so, in a file named _form.html.erb (under the same folder where show.html.erb is), put your form code and then from the show.html.erb use

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

Then you could use your from also from other views